# How to pass data from fragment to adapter class?

Tags: android

> i am having value of `companyName` In `Myfragment` class I need to pass this `companyName`value to `MyAdapter` Class. And without moving from `Myfragment` to `MyAdapter` activity. Can someone please tell me what to do? I am getting confused with every match I got on other websites.

**This is My Adapter Class**

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
Log.d("test",""+deliveryListBeans.size());
LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)ct.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_for_delivery_list,null);
Button delivered=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.do_delivered);
delivered.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent deliveryUpdate=new Intent(ct, MyOwn.class);
        deliveryUpdate.putExtra("invoiceId",dlb.getInvoiceNo());
        ct.startActivity(deliveryUpdate);
    }
});
return v;
```

}

> In `setOnClickListener` I need `companyName` value from `fragment` class so that i can use it in URL.

**This is My Fragment Class**

```
public class DeliveryList extends Fragment {
private List<DeliveryListBean> dlblistbean= new ArrayList<DeliveryListBean>();
ListView listview;
Button delivered;
String companyName;}
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// Inflate the layout for this fragment
final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_delivery_list,container,false);
listview=(ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.deliveryListView);
companyName=this.getArguments().getString("companyName");
listview.setAdapter(deliveryListAdapter);
return rootView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your adapter class

```
public class MyAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    private String mCompanyName;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, String companyName) {
        mContext = context;
        mCompanyName = companyName;
    }
}
```

Comment: getting null value for the `companyName`.

Comment: @Jithendra Sai what type is your value? replace the `String` with your value type EX: int, long, String,...

Comment: Your answer is not understable. can you be more specific with code. And the value if you are asking for `companyName` it is `string`